# Tags do Google Adwords e Analytics

Tags: asp, google

Como são as tags do Google AdWords e Analytics?
Alguém poderia me explicar como as reconheço e onde são encontradas em um site?
O site está em ASP Clássico. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo da página onde estamos:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () { (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments) }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', 'UA-5620270-42');        
ga('set', 'dimension1', '2604985');         
ga('set', 'dimension2', '|google|');         
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Coisas comuns nestes scripts que têm gerações/versões diferentes é a chave do cliente, neste caso `UA-5620270-42` e a variável `ga` que tanto quanto me lembro é usada em todas as variantes.

Comment: Legal @Sergio, e no caso essa function fica em um lugar especifico ? Home talvez ?

Comment: @AndreeH tem de ficar em todas as páginas. Só assim o Google sabe que uma página foi aberta. É comun colocar no footer por exemplo.

Comment: Entendi, Obrigado @Sergio.